# LWC - Remove a specific record Id from an array Of Objects - Update and re-render updated array's data

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-message-service

I am currently working on an LWC project leveraging the Lightning Messaging System to share information between unrelated components all present on the same lightning page.

[image: Lightning Page's User Interface]

Here is the main use case:

1. The **houseCard** component publishes the house's Id to remove from the **houseTileList** component through a Message Channel when the user clicks the ***Remove From List*** red button which is present on the right side of the page

***houseCard.js***

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

//House__c Schema

import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Name'
import PICTURE_URL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Picture_URL__c'
import SALESPRICE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Sales_Price__c'
import NEIGHBORHOOD_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Neighborhood_Name__c'
import NB_OF_BED_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Nb_Of_Bed__c'
import NB_OF_BATH_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Nb_Of_Bath__c'
import NB_OF_FEATURES_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Nb_Of_Features__c'
import PROPERTY_TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/House__c.Property_Type__c'


// getFieldValue function is used to extract field values
import {getFieldValue} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

//lightning message service
import {publish,subscribe, MessageContext, unsubscribe} from 'lightning/messageService'
import HOUSE_SELECTED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/HouseSelected__c'
import HOUSE_REMOVE_FROM_LIST_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/HouseRemoveFromList__c'



export default class HouseCard extends LightningElement {

    /// load content for LMS
    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext

    //exposing fields to make them available in the template
    salesPrice = SALESPRICE_FIELD;
    nbOfBed = NB_OF_BED_FIELD;
    nbOfBath = NB_OF_BATH_FIELD;
    nbOfFeatures = NB_OF_FEATURES_FIELD;
    propertyType = PROPERTY_TYPE_FIELD;
    neighborhood = NEIGHBORHOOD_FIELD;

    //Id of House__c to display data
    recordId 

    // house fields displayed with specific format
    houseName;
    housePictureUrl;    

    //subscription reference for houseSelected
    houseSelectionSubscription 

    handleRecordLoaded(event){
        const {records} = event.detail;
        const recordData = records[this.recordId];
        this.houseName = getFieldValue(recordData, NAME_FIELD);
        this.housePictureUrl = getFieldValue(recordData, PICTURE_URL_FIELD);
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.subscribeHandler()
    }

    subscribeHandler(){
        this.houseSelectionSubscription = subscribe(this.messageContext, HOUSE_SELECTED_MESSAGE, (message)=>this.handleHouseSelected(message))
    }
    handleHouseSelected(message){
        this.recordId = message.houseId
    }

    handleRemoveFromList(){
        console.log("House Id To Remove " , this.recordId)
        publish(this.messageContext, HOUSE_REMOVE_FROM_LIST_MESSAGE, {
            houseId:this.recordId
         })
    }

    disconnectedCallback(){
        unsubscribe(this.houseSelectionSubscription)
        this.houseSelectionSubscription = null
    }
}
```

***houseTileList.js***

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getHouses from '@salesforce/apex/HouseController.getHouses'

// Lightning Message Service and a message channel
import {publish,subscribe,unsubscribe, MessageContext} from 'lightning/messageService'
import HOUSES_FILTERED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/HousesFiltered__c'
import HOUSE_SELECTED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/HouseSelected__c'
import HOUSE_DOUBLE_SELECTED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/HouseDoubleSelected__c'
import HOUSE_REMOVE_FROM_LIST_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/HouseRemoveFromList__c'


export default class HouseTileList extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId; 
    houses= [];
    error;
    filters = {}; 
    houseFilterSubscription;
    houseRemoveFromListSubscription;
    __removedId;
    __newHousesList=[];

    @wire(getHouses, {filters:'$filters'})
    housesHandler({data, error}){
        if(data){
            console.log(data);
            this.houses = data;
        }
        if(error){
            this.error = error;
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

     /**Load context for LMS */
     @wire(MessageContext)
     messageContext

     connectedCallback(){
         this.subscribeHandler();
     }

     subscribeHandler(){
         this.houseFilterSubscription = subscribe(this.messageContext, HOUSES_FILTERED_MESSAGE, (message)=>this.handleFilterChanges(message));
         this.houseRemoveFromListSubscription = subscribe(this.messageContext, HOUSE_REMOVE_FROM_LIST_MESSAGE, (message)=>this.handleRemoveFromList(message));
     }

     handleFilterChanges(message){
         console.log(message.filters)
         this.filters ={...message.filters}
     }

     handleRemoveFromList(message){
        console.log('Received Id', message.houseId)
        this.__removedId = message.houseId
        this.__newHousesList = Array.from(this.houses);
        console.log('Houses list before remove event: ', this.__newHousesList) 
        console.log('Removed Id', this.__removedId)
        
     }

     handleHouseSelected(event){
        console.log("selected house Id " , event.detail)
        publish(this.messageContext, HOUSE_SELECTED_MESSAGE, {
            houseId:event.detail
         })
     }

     handleDoubleSelected(event){

        console.log("Double selected house Id " , event.detail)
        publish(this.messageContext, HOUSE_DOUBLE_SELECTED_MESSAGE, {
            houseId:event.detail
         })

    }

     disconnectedCallback(){
        unsubscribe(this.houseFilterSubscription)
        unsubscribe(this.houseRemoveFromListSubscription)
        this.houseFilterSubscription = null
        this.houseRemoveFromListSubscription = null
    }
}
```

2. The **houseTileList** component subscribes to the Message Channel and receives the house's Id to remove

My challenge is the following:

1. The **houses** property in **houseTileList** component contains all the houses displayed on the UI side
2. I would like to remove the received Id form the **houses** property
3. Make sure that my components perceives the mutation and reactively re-renders the updtaded property on the UI side

Here are the steps that I followed in order to achieve this:

- ***In the houseCard.js file***

1. Verified that the id to remove is properly sent from the **houseCard** component when the button is clicked

[image]

- ***In the houseTileList.js file*** -> ***handleRemoveFromList*** method

2. Verified that the Id to remove is received by the houseTileList component

[image]

3. Tried to filter out this specific Id from the **houses** array of objects using the following code:

```
        console.log('Houses list before filter: ', this.houses)// Verifying Initial Houses List's format and data content
        this.__newHousesList = [...this.houses];// Shallow copy of the original array
        console.log('New Houses list before filter: ', this.__newHousesList) // Verifying New Houses List's format and data content
        this.houses = this.__newHousesList.filter(item => item.Id !== this.__removedId)// Filter operation on New Houses List to remove Id 
        console.log('Houses list after the filter operation: ', this.houses)// Verifying Updated Houses List's format and data content
```

Here the console's output:

1. Initial **houses** list is populated

[image]

2. Shallow copy and filter operations are not working

[image]

It looks like the shallow copy I attempted is not working as I am receiving a Proxy with an empty array. This makes the subsequent filter operation non functional and the houses array is not updated accordingly.

I was wondering if someone could provide me with some insights, best practices or assistance regarding this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is add the @track decorator to houses. Arrays and objects don't automatically update in the UI without it.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators

As to why the shallow copy isn't working, I'm not sure... it ought to be, as I've used the same pattern before.

Comment: Thank you Rob. The @track decorator solved the issue! Many Thanks.